# ui-router ui-grid gridApi undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-grid

I have a controller which initializes the `gridOptions` of my `ui-grid`. When working without `ui-router`, the data loaded perfectly (for now from a json-file). I get them with 
`$http.get('...').success()`.

I brought `ui-router` into play and all works well, expect with the template that contains a `ui-grid`.

**I get Error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined". the error occurs in ui-grid.js on line 2705 
if (angular.isString($scope.uiGrid.data)) {...
```

It's the `uiGrid` object which is undefined. I tried using Resolve in the `$state` and my dummy data got loaded correctly in the controller, but unfortunately the problem remains. Hopefully you can help me fix this problem.

I've added a demo on plunkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/FzsxLDNGRWQrpGUKNHBa?p=preview
If you switch to the second view, you will see an empty ui-grid. Chrome developper tools report the TypeError.
Hopefully this helps in solving it. Many thanks for your answers.

Comment: There is no way of answering this question without any code. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and include the code where your error originates.

Comment: Agree with previous comment.  Some code and better yet a work/non-working demo is needed to debug and answer your question.  That said, seems like your grid is looking for data that doesn't exist yet.  Take a look at the resolve property in ui-router: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Your plunker almost works. You just need to fix the capitalization of your view2 controller.

change:

```js
controller: 'view2Controller',
```

to

```js
controller: 'View2Controller',
```

Tada :)

**PS**: When you use $inject you need to supply it as a property of the actual function object for your controller. If you were to minimize this code it would break.